# C# Regex - cut from end, but with a twist

Tags: c#, regex, windows-runtime

I have a list of strings I have to iterate through and remove something from the end. The strings look like this, usually:

```
String first = "Something here (SMM)";
String second = "Something else (&)";
String third = "Something here (1922) (IJK)";
```

What I want to do is, remove the last pair of parentheses, no matter what their content is. I'm a dufus when it comes to Regex, so I'm open to suggestion on how to solve this particular issue.

EDIT:

Forgot about the results I want:

```
String firstFinal = "Something here";
String secondFinal = "Something else";
String thirdFinal = "Something here (1922)";
```

Comment: So `third` would be `Something here (1922)`?

Comment: Exactly. I'll add the outcome patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following pattern should do what you're after:

```
\s\([^)]*\)$
```

Breaking that down:

`\s` matches the white space between the last required character and the opening parenthesis

`\(` is a literal parenthesis

`[^)]*` is anything that's not a `)`

`\)` is a literal closing parenthesis

`$` is the end of the string

This code

```
string pattern = @"\s\([^)]*\)$";

String first = "Something here (SMM)";
String second = "Something else (&)";
String third = "Something here (1922) (IJK)";

first = Regex.Replace(first, pattern, "");
second = Regex.Replace(second, pattern, "");
third = Regex.Replace(third, pattern, "");

Console.WriteLine(first);
Console.WriteLine(second);
Console.WriteLine(third);
```

Will print

> Something here
>
> Something else
>
> Something here (1922)

Comment: I've always called "[" a bracket, "(" is a parenthesis

Comment: @petelids -What if the third string was "Something here (1922) (IJK) testing"? I don't think that regular expression would work correctly.

Comment: @Ntellect13 - you're quite right, it would leave that string as-is. It's not clear from the OP what should happen in that situation.

Comment: @reggaeguitar - In the UK we typically call `(` and `)` brackets with `[` and `]` being _square brackets_. However, I suspect more readers would use parenthesis so I've updated the answer :).

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just create a method that you can pass the strings into to give you the output?:

```
    string first = stripped("Something here (SMM)");

    public string stripped(string stripper)
    {
        int indexOfFirst = stripper.LastIndexOf('(');
        int indexOfSecond = stripper.LastIndexOf(')');
        string output = stripper.Remove(indexOfFirst, (indexOfSecond - indexOfFirst) + 1);
        return output;
    }
```